# How to circumvent File not found error?

Tags: delphi

Sometimes it is weird to encounter File not Found Error in running. But we do not know how to bypass the error. There is a line:

```
  AHash := THash.Create();
  assign(F,Getcurrentdir+'\data.txt');
  reset(F);//File not Found
  while not EOF(F) do
  ...
```

This(Error) is not always the case. Sometimes it prompts error, sometimes it works well.
We do not know why and how to fix it.
Thank you very much in advance.

Or is there a function to update current dir before assign the file. Will this work?

data.txt is a resource that is packaged and installed to user's side and is permanently resided in application.exe dir. While our program is running, will the Getcurrentdir func change the actual current dir that the data.txt is located? it may not be the case.

Comment: My advice is to make sure that the file exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the file exists using the `FileExists`(filename) function. Its in `sysutils.pas`.

If you think the file not found error is not correct, maybe you don't have enough rights to use the file. Or maybe the file is not on the location you expect it.

If you think the file is only sometimes "not found" due to sheer magical reasons beyond human understanding, you can use the following function. But its better to find the real reason why the file is not there when it should be there.

```
function TryOpenFile(const AFileName: string; const AMaxTries: Integer; var AFile: File): Boolean;
var
  tries : Integer;
begin
  tries := 0;
  Result := false;
  while not Result and (tries<=AMaxTries) do begin
    try
      assign(AFile,AFileName);
      reset(AFile);
      Result := True;
    except 
      on e: EFileNotFoundException do begin
        Inc(tries);
        // Add delay if you wish.
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Do we have to use that file exists function, the file is there in the dir. But it still prompts error sometimes.

Comment: This is not always the case. I mean sometimes it occurs, sometimes it is ok.

Comment: +1 by `...But its better to find the real reason why the file is not there when it should be there`

Comment: Thank you RRUZ, It seems other applications are running, it is comparatively more the case, we are still checking. Thank you.

Comment: One warning with using FileExists- The file might be deleted or otherwise become unavailable between the 'FileExists' call and any attempt to load/read it, so even if you do check for it's existence, always trap the 'not found' exception anyway, just in case.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this:

```
{$I-}
assign(F,Getcurrentdir+'\data.txt');
reset(F);
if (ioResult=0) then begin
  while not EOF(F) do
  ...
{$I+}
```

The $I directive turns off automatic error checking, thus you have to check for errors in your own code by using ioResult. If on, then IO errors will result in exceptions.
Be aware: you will need to check for ioResult with every reset/read/write statement.
The file might exist, but still not be available because the user doesn't have access rights.

Comment: Yeah, old but still very effective. :-) I was already using this directive in 1988 with the old Turbo Pascal, if I'm not mistaken. (Did I just confess that I'm old too?)

Answer (score 1):

GetCurrentDir() may not always return the directory you need - the "current" dir may have changed. Why do you use GetCurrentDir() in the first place if the file you're trying to open is not there? Ensure you open the file from its actual directory. How to do that depends on how and when the file is generated. Of course putting some error control to handle the error is ok, but if you expect to find such a file that's should not happen but in "exceptional" situations.

Comment: how do yo know the current directory is not what @user482742 needs?  I have lot of programs that works on files on the current directory and GetCurrentDir() (in that situation) always returns exactly the directory I need.

Comment: Because if he doesn't find a file that should be there it means the current directory may have been changed. It *can* change. And he asks if there is a way to update the current dir before assigning the file (SetCurrentDirectory, BTW). If it works for you good, but that's his application, not yours.
And how do you know that the current directory is what he needs? And what is better? "Circumvent" an error or try to understand what the program is actually trying to do and fix the real cause of it?

Comment: There is a possibility that a badly behaving component is mucking with the current directory, Raymond Chen has just blogged about a similar problem here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/11/09/10087919.aspx

Comment: +1 for suggesting the cause could have been a change of the current directory.